# how to replace a dataframe row with NaN if it doesn't contain a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HDdv.png)

I am working with the data frame shown in the link above.  I want to make all rows that do not contain the words 'Yes' or 'No' be replaced with NaN.

Comment: please post the output of `dataframe_name.head()` as text, so we can cut and paste it to help

Comment: `df.loc[~df.met.isin(['yes','no']), 'met'] = np.nan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.Met = np.where(~df.Met.isin(['Yes', 'No']), np.nan, df.Met)
```

Try this.